# Python xml.etree.ElementTree Problems

Tags: python, xml

NEVER MIND - I FOUND MY REAL ISSUE, IT WAS FURTHER ON IN MY CODE THAT I REALIZED.

I am having problems getting `xml.etree.ElementTree` to work like I expect it to.

```
xmlData = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><suggestedmatches><destination><sortOrder>1</sortOrder><destinationType>destinationType1</destinationType></destination><destination><sortOrder>2</sortOrder><destinationType>destinationType2</destinationType></destination></suggestedmatches>"
root = ET.fromstring(xmlData)
logging.debug("DIAG: %s: root.tag = %s"
  % (FUNCTION_NAME, root.tag))
logging.debug("DIAG: %s: root = %r" % (FUNCTION_NAME, ET.tostring(root)))
destinations = root.findall("destination")
logging.debug('DIAG: %s: destinations = %r' % (FUNCTION_NAME, ET.tostring(destinations)))
```

I'm trying to figure out why I can't find `destinations` in `root`.

```
DEBUG:root:DIAG: findDestinations(): root.tag = suggestedmatches
DEBUG:root:DIAG: findDestinations(): root = b'<suggestedmatches><destination><sortOrder>1</sortOrder><destinationType>destinationType1</destinationType></destination><destination><sortOrder>2</sortOrder><destinationType>destinationType2</destinationType></destination></suggestedmatches>'
ERROR:root:findDestinations(): Encountered exception on root.findall() - 'list' object has no attribute 'iter'
```

And if I add the following code after I get `root`, I am seeing each of the destinations listed in the log:

```
for destination in root:
  destinationList.append(destination)
  logging.debug('DIAG: %s: destination.tag = %s'
    % (FUNCTION_NAME, destination.tag))
```

This same code is working in a different script, so I'm not sure why it's not working here.

Comment: What is `ET` here? Is it a built-in class? Or is it from some third-party package?

Comment: Got it! It's import alias for `ElementTree`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `None` because `ET.dump` writes to `sys.stdout` and you are logging return of `dump` which is `None`.

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.dump):

> xml.etree.ElementTree.dump(elem)
>
> Writes an element tree or element structure to sys.stdout. This function should be used for debugging only.
>
> The exact output format is implementation dependent. In this version, it’s written as an ordinary XML file.
>
> elem is an element tree or an individual element.

Try using `tostring` method instead of `dump`.

```
logging.debug("DIAG: %s: root = %r" % (FUNCTION_NAME, ET.tostring(root)))
```

Comment: Thanks, that explains the weirdness I was seeing in the output.   Please see my updates to my question above, the problem is that I can't seem to extract out the data..